# ¿Cómo puedo habilitar el zoom a una imagen svg que está cargada en un WebView y a la vez el WebView está cargado en un Fragment?

Tags: java, android-studio, webview

Este el código que tengo en el Java:

```
package com.example.facien.apliacionfacien;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FFisica1 extends Fragment {

Button btn1;
WebView wView;
TextView textView2;

public FFisica1() {
    // Required empty public constructor


}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finformatica1, container, false);

    String url = "file:///android_asset/nitro/administrativo.svg";
    WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);




    return  rootView;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución fue esta:

```
package com.example.facien.apliacionfacien;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FFisica1 extends Fragment {

Button btn1;
WebView wView;
TextView textView2;

public FFisica1() {
    // Required empty public constructor


}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finformatica1, container, false);

    String url = "file:///android_asset/nitro/administrativo.svg";
    WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    view.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);




    return  rootView;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas

#### habilitar el Zoom en el contenido de un WebView.

Simplemente habilita las propiedades:

> [setBuiltInZoomControls](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean)) Establece si WebView debe usar sus
> mecanismos de zoom incorporados. Los mecanismos de zoom incorporados
> incluyen controles de zoom en pantalla, que se muestran sobre el
> contenido de WebView, y el uso de un gesto de pellizco para controlar
> el zoom.  Si estos controles en pantalla se muestran o no se pueden configurar con [setDisplayZoomControls](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDisplayZoomControls(boolean)) (boolean). El valor predeterminado es falso.

Ejemplo:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
```